# Vim: change prompt on shell escape

Tags: shell, vim

I often use `:sh` while editing a file in vim so that I can perform small tasks like git commits before getting back to editing the file. However, sometimes I get confused whether my shell was started by my terminal emulator or it was started as a vim subshell, so typing `exit` at the prompt always runs the risk of closing the terminal emulator by accident rather than going back to my vim editing session. Is there a way to have vim modify my prompt, perhaps by the `$PS1` environment variable, when I start a shell from vim so that I know whether I'm in a subshell started by vim or not?

Comment: Use `ctrl+z` to suspend your VIM session instead of `:sh`?

Comment: When I run `:sh` from `vim` I already get a different prompt, although I'm not sure where it's defined. Do you have a custom prompt setup in your bash profile?

Comment: I use zsh, but yes, my prompt is heavily customized.

Comment: @mbratch I removed your addition of the `zsh` tag because this question is not zsh specific. In fact, it's not specific to any shell.

Comment: OK, I thought it might be since I use `bash` and it's behavior does not appear to be the same.

Comment: zsh is basically a superset of bash. That's not exactly true, but it's close enough to get a good idea of how zsh works. Though zsh's behavior is not exactly relevant to my question...

Comment: What I found is the behavior is different if I do `:!sh` versus `:sh`. In the former case, it gives me a different prompt. In the latter, I get the same prompt. I hadn't realized that before. :)

Comment: @mbratch - `:!sh` is the same as running `sh` from your shell prompt (`sh` is usually the original Bourne shell, or an emulator of the original Bourne shell, both of which are different from bash, which is the Bourne-again shell), while `:sh` will run whatever shell or command you have configured vim to use. I think by default, vim will use whatever is stored in `$SHELL`.

Comment: @jayhendren yep, I realize that. Earlier I had commented that the behavior on my system was different and I didn't know why until yesterday I was in `vim` and did my escape-to-shell and remembered I was in the habit of doing `:!sh` which is why my prompt was different. Thanks for commenting back with the details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you do `:sh`, a few additional Vim-specific shell variables are available to you. On this machine, I have:

```
$MYVIMRC
$VIM
$VIMRUNTIME
```

You can use `$VIM`, for example, in your `*rc` file like this:

```
if [ $VIM ]
then
  # set your vim-specific PS1 here
else
  # set your normal PS1 here
fi
```

Bonus: in GVim/MacVim the pseudo terminal you get when you do `:sh` is incapable of displaying colors. because Vim exports it as `dumb`, you can use the same logic as above to have a monochrome prompt when in GVim/MacVim and a color prompt in your shell:

```
if [ $TERM == 'dumb' ]
then
  # no colors
else
  # colors
fi
```

Comment: This works best for me. I have those same environment variables as well. Thanks very much!

Comment: I like this, because I find myself once in awhile shelling out from vim, forgetting I did so, and starting vi again.  Changing prompts reminds me I'm in a vim shell.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a rc file to set a different $PS1 and source it inside vim like this

```
set shell=/bin/bash\ --rcfile\ ~/.bashforvimrc
```

check here http://nothingtobedoneforall.wordpress.com/2007/02/25/setting-shell-prompt-for-vim/

Update from Neatu Qvidiu Gabriel's comments,

it's preferably to execute source ~/.bashrc before assigning to PS1. Because otherwise you lose all your predefined configuration in bashrc

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! This will get me started on the right path. I'll accept your answer when I have a moment to look into this and confirm that it works for me.

Comment: vim chokes on the `--rcfile` option. I'm using vim version 7.3 . Do you know where I can find documentation for the `set shell` command? EDIT: whoops, didn't see that it's a shell command flag rather than a vim `set shell` flag.

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html near the 60 percept or you can search 'shell' 'sh'

Comment: Got it. See my edit to my comment above. I also managed to get the info I wanted from `:help set` ;)

Comment: The only thing missing from that blog post is that it's preferably to execute `source ~/.bashrc` before assigning to PS1. Because otherwise you lose all your predefined configuration in bashrc :)

Answer (score 0):

I use these two functions, one for git (always on), one for vim (visible when in a shell spawned by :sh):

```
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}
is_vim_sh() {
    if [ "x$VIM" != "x" ]; then
        echo " [vim]"
    fi
}
export PS1="\u@\h\[\033[32m\]\w\[\033[33m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$(is_vim_sh)$ "
```

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of GVim/MacVim, `:h guioptions` [now support](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/VcyMs-s1l-M) the following flag:

```
  '!'   External commands are executed in a terminal window.  Without
        this flag the MS-Windows GUI will open a console window to
        execute the command.  The Unix GUI will simulate a dumb
        terminal to list the command output.
        The terminal window will be positioned at the bottom, and grow
        upwards as needed.
```

Set `:set go+=!`, run `:sh` in GVim/MacVim, and be surprised :).